# Is there a general solution for the differential equation $f''(x) = f(f(x))$?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, functional-equations

I'm currently an undergraduate studying differential equations and I've been fixated on the differential equation $f''(x) = f(f(x))$ for the past 2 days. I can't seem to crack it but it feels like it should have a general solution?

Comment: An answer already [exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916967/how-do-you-solve-fx-ffx) on MSE

Comment: @leibnewtz I think this version has $f''$ and not $f'$?

Comment: @WillieWong You're right, I didn't read it correctly

Comment: See, for example, http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/AMEN/papers/001021.pdf

Comment: What is modeled by such equations? Do they arise in applications?

Comment: @MarkWildon, where is the answer on MSE?  The [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916967/how-do-you-solve-fx-ffx) [linked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384174/is-there-a-general-solution-for-this-differential-equation-fx-ffx#comment978195_384174) by @‍leibnewtz is a different one, [per](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384174/is-there-a-general-solution-for-this-differential-equation-fx-ffx#comment978196_384174) @‍WillieWong.

Comment: Name of the paper [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384174/is-there-a-general-solution-for-this-differential-equation-fx-ffx#comment978204_384174) by @EFinat-S:  [Li, Cheng, and Lu - Closed form solutions of iterative functional differential equations](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/AMEN/papers/001021.pdf), #1 in [AMEN Volume 1](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/AMEN/papers/2001.html).

Comment: for every solution $f$. a new solution is $-f(-x)$. This nconsists  with holomorphic solution provided by Prof. Bryant which is an odd function. another simple fact is that any such solution commute with its second derivative so this possibly exclude a lot of entire holomorphic solutions.

Comment: @Ali Targhavi: there are no entire transcendental solutions (the RHS grows faster than the LHS). And the answer of Engelhardt shows that there are no polynomial solutions.

Answer (score 30):

**Remark:**  I had a little time to write a draft of my notes on the proofs of the claims I make below and have posted it on my home webpage [here](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ebryant/MOQuestion384174.pdf).  (It would have made a very long post on MO, so I decided that it would be better to just link it to a file in my public directory.)

There are many *local* solutions of this equation.  For example, suppose that one starts with a $C^2$ function $f$ on an interval $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'$ is positive on $I$ and $f(I)$ is disjoint from $I$.  Then an inverse $g:f(I)\to I$ of $f:I\to f(I)$ exists and is $C^2$.  Now define $f$ on the interval $f(I)$ so that $f(y) = f''(g(y))$ for $y\in f(I)$.  Then for $x\in I$, we will have $x = g(y)$ for some $y\in f(I)$ and, of course, $y = f(x)$.  Then $f''(x) = f''(g(y)) = f(y) = f(f(x))$ for all $x\in I$.

These sorts of 'rough' solutions are constructed without any fixed points.  Solutions with fixed points are much more rigid.  A $C^2$ solution on an open domain $D$ such that $f(D)\subset D$ must be smooth on $D$, since $f''=f{\circ}f$, implying that if $f$ is $C^k$, then $f$ must be $C^{k+2}$.  In fact, with a little effort, one can show that a $C^2$ solution with an contracting fixed point must be real-analytic in a neighborhood of the fixed point, since the equation $f''=f{\circ}f$ allows one to prove an estimate of the form $|f^{(k)}|\le C^k\,k!$ for some constant $C$ on a neighborhood of the fixed point.

**Note 1:**  For every constant $b\in\mathbb{C}$, there is a unique formal power series with lowest order term $bz$ that satisfies $f''(z) = f(f(z))$.  The first few terms are
$$
f(z) = bz+\frac{{b}^{2}}{3!}\,{z}^{3}
+{\frac {{b}^{3} \left( {b}^{2}{+}1 \right)}{5!}}\,{z}^{5}
+{\frac {{b}^{4} \left( {b}^{6}{+}{b}^{4}{+}11\,{b}^{2}{+}1\right)}{7!}}\,{z}^{7}+\cdots.\tag1
$$
When $|b|<1$, this series converges absolutely and uniformly on the disk $|z|^2\le 6\bigl(1{-}|b|\bigr)$, and satisfies $|f(z)|\le |z|$ there.  See the Addendum below for a sharper (but still not sharp) estimate of the radius of convergence.

*Update (1 Mar 2021):* One can show that, when $b$ is a small negative real number, the above function $f$ extends real-analytically and periodically to $\mathbb{R}$ and gives a $1$-parameter family of nontrivial solutions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  In particular, such an $f$ extends holomorphically to a strip of fixed width about $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$.  (Meanwhile, when $-1<b<0$, the radius of convergence of the power series (1) is only $r(|b|)\in(0,\infty)$ (see the Addendum below), which is a very different behavior from that when $0<b<1$.)

**Addendum to Note 1:**  One can show that, when $0<b<1$, the real-analytic odd function $f$ that equals the power series (1) on its interval of convergence extends real-analytically to a bounded interval $\bigl(-r(b),r(b)\bigr)\subset\mathbb{R}$ on which $|f(x)|<|x|$ and that $\lim_{x\to r(b)^-}f(x)=r(b)$.  In particular, $f:\bigl(-r(b),r(b)\bigr)\to\bigl(-r(b),r(b)\bigr)$ is a real-analytic diffeomorphism with a single contracting fixed point at $x=0$.  Moreover, the formal series converges to $f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\bigl(-r(b),r(b)\bigr)$, and $f$ cannot be extended real-analytically to any larger interval.  (There are some indications that $f$ may extend *smoothly* beyond $x = r(b)$, in which case, $x=r(b)$ would become an expanding fixed point of $f$.)  Also, $r:(0,1)\to(0,\infty)$ is a continuous, decreasing bijection, and
$$
\frac{\sqrt{6\bigl(1{-}b\bigr)}}{b}
> r(b)> \begin{cases}
\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac3{2b}} & \text{for}\ 0<b\le\tfrac12,\\
\\
\sqrt{6(1{-}b)} & \text{for}\ \tfrac12\le b<1,
\end{cases}
$$
from which it follows that, for $b=1$, the radius of convergence of the series is $0$.

**Note 2:**  More generally, for any two constants $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$, there is a formal power series
$$
f(z) = a+b\,(z{-}a) 
+\frac{a}{2!}\,(z{-}a)^2
+\frac{b^2}{3!}\,(z{-}a)^3
+\frac{ab(b{+}1)}{4!}\,(z{-}a)^4
+\cdots\tag2
$$
that has $a$ as a formal fixed point, i.e., $f(a) = a$, so that the composition $f(f(z))$ makes sense as a power series centered at $z = a$
and, formally, $f'(a) = b$, that satisfies $f''(z) = f(f(z))$ as formal power series centered at $z = a$.  Moreover, this is the unique power series centered at $z=a$ that has $f(a) = a$ and $f'(a) = b$ and satisfies $f''(z) = f(f(z))$ as formal power series.

As in the case $a=0$, when $|b|<1$, so that $f$ is a 'formal contraction' on a neighborhood of $a$, it turns out that the series converges absolutely and uniformly on a disc of the form $|z-a| \le r(a,b)$ for some $r(a,b)>0$, so this gives a two-parameter family of local solutions with a contracting fixed point.

**Note 3:** The (two) multivalued solutions described by Michael Engelhardt have fixed points and hence are (analytic continuations of) solutions of the type (2).  One can see this as follows:  These (multivalued) solutions can be written in the form
$$
f(x) = i\sqrt{2}\,\left(\frac{x}{i\sqrt{2}}\right)^b,\qquad
\text{where}\  b = \tfrac12(1\pm i\sqrt{7}).
$$
Clearly, $a\in\mathbb{C}$ will be a fixed point, i.e., $f(a) = a$ if and only if
$$
1 = \left(\frac{a}{i\sqrt{2}}\right)^{b-1},
$$
and this happens (for $b = \tfrac12(1+i\sqrt7)$) when, for some integer $k$,
$$
a = a_k = i\sqrt{2}\, e^{i\pi k(1+i\sqrt7)/2} = i^{k+1}\sqrt{2}\,\left(e^{-\pi\sqrt7}\right)^{k/2}.
$$
Moreover, we have
$$
f'(a_k) = b\left(\frac{a_k}{i\sqrt2}\right)^{b-1} = b,
$$
so $|f'(a_k)| = |b| = \sqrt 2>1$, which implies that the fixed point is a repelling fixed point.

This is interesting because it implies that the formal power series (2) for $(a_k,b)$ must have a positive radius of convergence, even though $|b|>1$.  This led me to speculate that maybe the formal power series (2) might have a positive radius of convergence for any $(a,b)\in\mathbb{C}$, but Will Sawin (in a comment below) pointed out that this cannot be true.

Comment: This shows that the question, as stated, has little sense. Further conditions must be imposed on $f$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko A reasonable request would be to have $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $f\in C^2$. So far all proposed "solutions" fail it dramatically (except the trivial solution $f\equiv 0$).

Comment: I would appreciate if you read my comments to the OP post. does this implies that we have no entire holomorphic solution?

Comment: In particular is there an entire functiondifferent from exponential function   and  linear function?which commute with its second derivative

Comment: And  sin z or  cosz?

Comment: @AliTaghavi, $\cos$ does not commute with its second derivative $-\cos$, because $\cos(-\cos(z))=\cos(\cos(z))\neq -\cos(\cos(z))$. It is strange that this property distinguishes $\sin$ from $\cos$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I think "has little sense" is a little strong for a difficult, interesting question, which just needs some mild additional condition to be imposed.

Comment: In equation (1), it seems the coefficient of $z^{2n+1}$ always contains the term $b^{(n^2+1)} / n!$ by induction (in $f(f(z))$, ignore all the terms but $bz$ from the inner $f$.  So for $b$ positive real, this coefficient is always at least $b^{(n^2+1)} / n!$ which for $b>1$ grows faster than any exponential, hence the radius of convergence really is zero in this case.

Comment: @WillSawin:  Actually, it's $b^{n^2+1}/(2n{+}1)!$, but that still will grow faster than any exponential, so your point is valid, which makes it surprising that the series would have a positive radius of convergence for any $b$ with $|b|>1$.

Comment: @MattF.  Yes it is interesting that this property distinguishes cos from sin. It would be interesting to find a function different from linear function, sin or sinh  and cosh which satisfies the commutativity property $f''\circ f=f \circ f''$. all of these satisfy the trivial equation $y''=0$ or $y''=y$. another example is the solution of $y''=x$.

Comment: @MattF.  Any way I think the equation is interesting since it seems that these kind of equations are necessary conditions for $f''\circ f=f\circ f''$    https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1984-283-02/S0002-9947-1984-0737892-8/S0002-9947-1984-0737892-8.pdf   so it would be interesting to classify all entire function with this  commutative  property. So it would be interesting to consider the entire version of the main question via commutativity point of view.

Comment: @AliTaghavi Another example is $f(z) = z^2/\sqrt2$ or more generally $f(z) = z^k/\sqrt{(k^2-k)^{k-1}}$.

Comment: @Will Savin: this is exactly what I wrote: that WITHOUT additional conditions it has little sense. DEPENDING on those additional conditions, it may be difficult, or not. But why it may be interesting, escapes me.

Comment: (I meant to write $(2n+1)!$ but unaccountably failed to). I wonder if we can show a positive radius of convergence for $a,b$ close to those in Michael Engelhardt's examples by a similar approach or whether the large first derivative still causes problems.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I understand about what you meant. I just think it's important, when a question needs additional conditions or other small changes, to express this in a way that can't be interpreted as very harsh criticism. To me a novel simple question with an unexpected answer is interesting - regardless of what set of pairs $(a,b)$ defines a convergent power series, I think the classification will be unexpected!

Comment: @fedja:  I have now suceeded in proving that there are nontrivial solutions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  The examples I construct are contractions to $x=0$, and hence are real-analytic.  Moreover, they are periodic.  See the Update (1 Mar 2021).

Answer (score 23):

The equation has solutions with powers, $f(x) = ax^b$. Inserting this ansatz, one has
$$
a b (b-1) x^{b-2} = a (a x^b)^b = a^{b+1} x^{b^2} \ ,
$$
so the requirements on $a$ and $b$ are
$$
b-2 = b^2 \ \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ b = \frac{1\pm i\sqrt{7} }{2}
$$
and
$$
b(b-1) = a^b \ \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ a = (b(b-1))^{1/b}
\ \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ a = (-2)^{1/b}$$

So this yields two solutions, which will have to be restricted to the complex $x$ plane with a cut to make sense of the non-integer exponents.

Comment: How do you know that there are no other solutions?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko - I do not know that. I certainly expect there are more. They won't be as simple.

Comment: It's an interesting fact that these two (multi-valued) solutions are, in fact, special cases of the solutions with fixed points that I mention in my answer. What's interesting is that the fixed points are *repelling* fixed points, since, at a fixed point $z$ of one of these solutions, one has $|f'(z)|=\sqrt{2}>1$.  In particular, this shows that the formal power series solutions around fixed points that I indicate can have a positive radius of convergence, even when the formal fixed point is repelling.  Perhaps the formal solutions with fixed point always have a positive radius of convergence?

Comment: @RobertBryant - Ah! I had been wondering whether these two solutions would fit into the general scheme you were developing. And one can make sense of them locally around a whole sequence of fixed points ... nice. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt:  You're welcome.  As Will Sawin pointed out in a comment to my answer, though, my speculation that the formal power series solutions might always have a positive radius of convergence was too optimistic; he showed that this cannot be true.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions are:

$$\displaystyle f_1(x) = e^{\frac{\pi}{3} (-1)^{1/6}} x^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}}$$
$$\displaystyle f_2(x) = e^{\frac{\pi}{3} (-1)^{11/6}} x^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}}$$

The solution technique can be found in [this paper](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/math/akca/papers/cheng.pdf).

For a general case, solution of the equation

$$f'(z)=f^{[m]}(z)$$

has the form

$$f(z)=\beta z^\gamma$$

where $\beta$ and $\gamma$ should be obtained from the system

$$\gamma^m=\gamma-1$$
$$\beta^{\gamma^{m-1}+...+\gamma}=\gamma$$

In your case $m=2$.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. It might also be useful to review the existing history of the post.